# Angular make canActivateGuard asynchronous

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, jwt, observable

I have a web application where there is a JWT token passed to the admin service. This JWT comes from the query URL as there is a redirect from another application. The constructor in the service checks for that URL and set the `token` value to it (if that params is there).

The problem I am facing is that the canActivateGuard fires too early. When this is called the observable to get the JWT in the service is not solved yet, so the JWT is always not there when the guard is being fired.

I have figure out that to make this work `isLoggedIn()` in the AdminService has to become an observable that listen to the changes in the URL, and the `canActivate()` in the guard has to subscribe to it, but can not make this works.

The below code is what I got so far

```
// Admin Service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {

  token: string;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

        activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
            (params) => {
                console.log('queryParams', params);
                if(localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
                    this.token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
                }
                else if(params['jwt']) {
                    localStorage.setItem('jwt', params['jwt']);
                    this.token = params['jwt'];
                }
            });
    }


    // Check that JWT is in local storage and valid
    isLoggedin() {
        return (localStorage.getItem('jwt') !== null && localStorage.getItem('jwt') !== 'undefined');
    }
}


// Can Activate guard
// Note that this.authService.isLoggedIn() is called before the set JWT in the service is solved

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AdminService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedin()) {
            console.log('all ok, proceed navigation to routed component')
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // start a new navigation to redirect to login page
            this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `snapshot`? `activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams`.

Comment: Not sure why would that change anything?

Comment: *"The problem I am facing is that the canActivateGuard fires too early. When this is called the observable to get the JWT in the service is not solved yet*". So.. using `snapshot` you don't have to subscribe to get the JWT..

Answer (score 0):

using `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and `RouterStateSnapshot` your problem will be get resolve, and you don't need to subscribe for JWT in your service.

Here is a sample of my code which i had used in my Angular2 application.

> auth-guard.ts

```
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthCookie } from '../shared/services/auth-cookies-handler';

@Injectable()
export default class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private _authCookie: AuthCookie) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this._authCookie.getAuth()) {
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.